# C1ReportDesigner subreport overflow to footer and not page breaking

Tags: templates, report, componentone

I am working with C1ReportDesigner which I am new to it. I have a sub-reports embedded with main report. When a column in sub-report content is huge it doesn't page break, instead it overflows to footer. How to page break and continue in next page in C1ReportDesigner?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the [KeepTogether](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1report/#C1.C1Report.4~C1.C1Preview.RenderObject~KeepTogether.html) property of the control within the subreport (having long text) is set to True. This property tends to keep the whole text together on a single page, hence ,at times, causing the overflowing of text over other sections.

Please make sure to set the KeepTogether property of Field (of Subreport) having long text is set to False.

Regards,
Mohita